# Custom Prometheus sink for Apache Flink?

Tags: java, time-series, apache-flink, grafana, prometheus

I have a time series logs processed by Apache Flink, and I want to plot the data of grafana, by first exporting it to Prometheus. Is there any example or a way to do so in java. Something like writing a custom sink in flink which will continuously sink data into prometheus.

Comment: So what is the problem? Have you tried something? Or you expect someone to code the sink for you? :) Flink Docs: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sinks First search on Google: https://www.bytefish.de/blog/apache_flink_series_4/

Comment: Actually, tried a lot. Read about Java client , flink documentation and lot of other sources over 2 days and did not get anything. I am here for a direction.

Comment: Also I have already visited those links. :-)

Comment: If it is a small number of values, the hack I have done is basically a null sink which exposes metrics from the values that are written to it. Then you just use the PrometheusMetricsReporter which will poll it. But this limits your time granularity and also does not give you fine control over the labels

Comment: I have lot of data that needs to be exposed, plus i need prometheus to read the event timestamp rather than putting its own timestamp thats why i am unable to use client libraries

Comment: This would be easy to do with the influxdb sink and grafana. Does it have to be Prometheus? There's an influxdb sink here: https://github.com/apache/bahir-flink/tree/master/flink-connector-influxdb

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for the Flink Metrics reporter which is available in current versions of Flink. It allows for reporting to Prometheus.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/deployment/metric_reporters.html